# Include parameter values with data for safe Export and Import

Tags: export, data

Usually, when saving data as dat. file I include information about the parameters used to generate the data in the file name. Could I include that information with the generated data in the dat. file, in such a way that I can `Import` and `Export` it effectively?

For example, assume we have a function $f(x)=a x+ b$ and we would like to obtain the set of data for {$x$, $f(x)$} with different values of $a$ and $b$:

```
f[x_] = a x + b; a = 1; b = 1;
data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, -3, 3, 0.1}];
```

when I use `Export["..\\data.dat", data]` this how it looks like

[image: screenshot of exported dat file in Notepad]

Can we add a header to the dat. file that contains the values of $a$ and $b$?

I would like something like the following:

[image: screenshot of Notepad, with a=1; b=1 in the first line]

Comment: It is certainly possible, but you will probably have to do it by hand, either by adding that information to the top of your data, or by outputting it to the file. Similarly for importing, you will have to process the imported data yourself to separate the values of the parameters from the data. A better choice would be a structured data format (JSON?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider perhaps a more structured approach to your data, maybe using JSON format or something similar that is built in:

```
Export[
  "myFile.json",
  {"parameters" -> {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 1}, 
   "data" -> data}, 
  "JSON"
]
```

This will generate a text file that is still human readable, although of course not as directly as a simple table, but the advantage is that it can be imported back with its metadata intact:

```
importedData = Import["myFile.json", "JSON"]

(* Out:
{"parameters" -> {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 1}, 
 "data" -> {{-3, -2}, {-2.9, -1.9}, {-2.8, -1.8}, {-2.7, -1.7}, {-2.6, -1.6}, 
            {-2.5, -1.5}, {-2.4, -1.4}, {-2.3, -1.3}, {-2.2, -1.2}, 
            {-2.1, -1.1}, {-2, -1}, {-1.9, -0.9}, {-1.8, -0.8}, {-1.7, -0.7},
            {-1.6, -0.6}, {-1.5, -0.5}, {-1.4, -0.4}, {-1.3, -0.3}, 
            {-1.2, -0.2}, {-1.1, -0.1}, {-1, 0}, {-0.9, 0.1}, {-0.8, 0.2}, 
            {-0.7, 0.3}, {-0.6, 0.4}, {-0.5, 0.5}, {-0.4, 0.6}, {-0.3, 0.7},
            {-0.2, 0.8}, {-0.1, 0.9}, {0, 1}, {0.1, 1.1}, {0.2, 1.2}, 
            {0.3, 1.3}, {0.4, 1.4}, {0.5, 1.5}, {0.6, 1.6}, {0.7, 1.7}, 
            {0.8, 1.8}, {0.9, 1.9}, {1, 2}, {1.1, 2.1}, {1.2, 2.2}, 
            {1.3, 2.3}, {1.4, 2.4}, {1.5, 2.5}, {1.6, 2.6}, {1.7, 2.7}, 
            {1.8, 2.8}, {1.9, 2.9}, {2, 3}, {2.1, 3.1}, {2.2, 3.2}, 
            {2.3, 3.3}, {2.4, 3.4}, {2.5, 3.5}, {2.6, 3.6}, {2.7, 3.7}, 
            {2.8, 3.8}, {2.9, 3.9}, {3, 4}}
}
*)
```

and from that you can get your parameters and data:

```
"parameters" /. importedData
"data" /. importedData
```