# how to create a list of machine-made index names

Tags: function-construction, indexed-variable

How can I create such lists of variables:

```
list1={sus1[t],sus2[t],sus3[t],...,sus99[t]};
list2={inf1[t],inf2[t],inf3[t],...,inf99[t]};
```

Consecutive `Integers` should be placed in between `sus` and `[t]` and between `inf` and `[t]` as in the above examples.

Earlier, @kglr did the following:

```
list = {das[t], das[t], das[t]};
Replace[list, {h_[a__] :> Symbol[SymbolName[h] <> "0"][a], 
 s_ :> Symbol[SymbolName[s] <> "0"]}, {1}]
```

Which replaces 0 only.

What I have in mind is a format like:

```
fn[sus_, n_, t_]:= something
```

and

```
fn[inf, 3, t]
```

should generate

```
{inf1[t], inf2[t], inf3[t]}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this with symbols? Your life will be significantly better by just using 2D arrays

Comment: @b3m2a1: How can I use 2D arrays?

Comment: BTW, "tailor-made" generally means hand-altered, that is, type them out by hand; what you really want is "machine-made" or "factory-made." The answer to your problem must already exist on site: `Table[ToExpression["das"<>ToString[k]][t], {k, 99}]` -- You can use `Symbol` instead of `ToExpression`.

Comment: @MichaelE2: I edited the title statement of my question. Let me try your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Yes, your answer works. You may put it as an answer if you like. Tugrul

Comment: @TugrulTemel just store your data in a list-of-list format or use indexed variables

Comment: I'd like to second @b3m2a1 's suggestion here. Don't bother with constructing variable names with strings. Instead use numerical indices. It's much more amenable to machine-manipulation down the line.

Comment: @MarcoB: I have string variable names used as the variables of a model, which is solved for the string variables. I have limited knowledge of programming, and therefore, I would appreciate if you give me a simple example of your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @Tugrul Yes I can see how that would be conceptually easier (indeed, I've done it myself in the past, and lived to regret it!). I think my suggestion is well exemplified by Bob Hanlon's answer below. Even more to the point may be to just keep working with lists of numbers if you only need numerical evaluation. Alternatively, I have been warming up to the use of `Association` or lists or `Rule`s to store data together with their metadata (see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235579/27951).

Comment: @MarcoB: Thanks for your reference, and I do not want to regret it later!! therefore, I will study the reference you gave me. I would be happy to hear from you if you make an improvement in the use of `Association` and `Rules`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

n = 3; (* Use any desired value *)
```

Use indexed variables

```
susV = Array[sus[#][t] &, n]

(* {sus[1][t], sus[2][t], sus[3][t]} *)

infV = Array[inf[#][t] &, n]

(* {inf[1][t], inf[2][t], inf[3][t]} *)
```

If you are going to assign values to the variables then the indexed variables will never show up in the output, just their values. Consequently, formatting would not be important. If however you want symbolic results (unlikely with vectors of length 99):

```
Format[sus[n_][t_]] := Subscript[sus, n][t];
Format[inf[n_][t_]] := Subscript[inf, n][t];
```

As much as possible, define functions with vector operations.

```
fn[t_] = susV.infV + infV // Simplify
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way:

```
list = Table[ToExpression["das"<>ToString[k]][t], {k, 99}];
```

One can use `Symbol` instead of `ToExpression`.

The closest related Q&A I've found is [Some challenge for a Table mixing between output number Variables and ToString symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132658/some-challenge-for-a-table-mixing-between-output-number-variables-and-tostring-s)

One finds these solutions already presented in many questions:

- [Site search for those using `ToExpression`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=toexpression+variable+tostring+table)
- [Site search for those using `Symbol`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=symbol+variable+tostring+table)